# Python regex for int with at least 4 digits

Tags: python, regex, int, match

I am just learning regex and I'm a bit confused here. I've got a string from which I want to extract an int with at least 4 digits and at most 7 digits. I tried it as follows:

```
>>> import re
>>> teststring = 'abcd123efg123456'
>>> re.match(r"[0-9]{4,7}$", teststring)
```

Where I was expecting 123456, unfortunately this results in nothing at all. Could anybody help me out a little bit here?

Comment: Wouldn't you be expecting `123456`?

Comment: @JonClements - Ah, yes. You are right. Excuse me. I corrected it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

@ExplosionPills is correct, but there would still be two problems with your regex.

First, `$` matches the *end* of the string. I'm guessing you'd like to be able to extract an int in the middle of the string as well, *e.g.* `abcd123456efg789` to return `123456`. To fix that, you want this:

```
r"[0-9]{4,7}(?![0-9])"
            ^^^^^^^^^
```

The added portion is a *negative lookahead assertion*, meaning, "...not followed by any more numbers." Let me simplify that by the use of `\d` though:

```
r"\d{4,7}(?!\d)"
```

That's better. Now, the second problem. You have no constraint on the left side of your regex, so given a string like `abcd123efg123456789`, you'd actually match `3456789`. So, you need a *negative lookbehind assertion* as well:

```
r"(?<!\d)\d{4,7}(?!\d)"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Works like a charm! I've got one more question; lets say I now want to find all numbers resembling years which are hidden in the string. This would mean that it consists of exactly 4 digits of which the first two are either 19 or 20 (years can range in my application from 1950s to 2050). Would you also know how I could find these numbers? I guess I would need findall() for this, but how do I match 4 digits with the first two being 19 or 20?

Comment: Easy. `r"(?<!\d)(?:19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d|2050)(?!\d)"`. Have fun :-)

Comment: I guess, in case you're not familiar with these constructs, I should explain some things. Ignore the `(?: ... )`; just pretend it's a group `( ... )`. And the `|` are alternation operators, like, "This OR this OR this."

Comment: Thanks for that! The | constructs I know from php, but what I wonder about is actually the ?: and the < at the beginning..?

Comment: The `(?: ... )` simply turns a group into a _non-capturing_ group. You know how `( ... )` normally _captures_ what's in between into variables like `$1`, `$2`, etc.? The `?:` simply prevents that. It's good practice to be explicit when you're not actually going to use the capture. The `<` at the beginning is just the syntax for a negative lookbehind assertion: `(?<! ... )`; the `<` is supposed to look like an arrow pointing behind.

Comment: Ah ,like that. Thanks a million for all this! It has really helped me a lot in both building my app, and (more importantly) learning about regex. So thanks again!

Comment: Yup, my pleasure. Happy coding.

Comment: You say "negative lookahead assertion" twice. Do you mean simply "lookahead assertion" the first time?

Comment: I believe the second one is _lookbehind_!

Answer (score 9):

`.match` will only match if the string *starts* with the pattern.  Use `.search`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
re.findall(r"[0-9]{4,7}", teststring)
```

Which will return a list of all substrings that match your regex, in your case ['123456']

If you're interested in just the first matched substring, then you can write this as:

```
next(iter(re.findall(r"[0-9]{4,7}", teststring)), None)
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the $, otherwise it only finds the last one.