# Regex matching 5-digit substrings not enclosed with digits

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract 5 continuous digits from the string

code I have written.

```
re.findall(r"((\D|^)*)\d\d\d\d\d((\D|$)*)", s)
```

but it can not pass the string

```
"Helpdesk-Agenten (m/w) Kennziffer: 12966"
```

The expected result is:

```
12966
```

Example 2:

```
#input
"Helpdesk-Agenten (m/w) Kennziffer: 12966abc"
# expected
12966
```

Example 3:

```
#input
"Helpdesk-Agenten (m/w) Kennziffer: 12966345"
# expected
"" (because the length of continuous digits is longer than 5)
```

Comment: maybe you could provide more examples of matches? should it match 12345abc?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks for the comment, added two examples

Comment: Here is another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348538/python-regex-for-int-with-at-least-4-digits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current regex (`((\D|^)*)\d\d\d\d\d((\D|$)*)`) used with `re.findall` won't return the digit chunks because they are not *captured*. More, the `(\D|^)*` and 
`(\D|$)*` parts are *optional* and that means they do not do what they are supposed to do, the regex will find 5 digit chunks inside longer digits chunks.

If you must find 5 digit chunk not enclosed with other digits, use

```
re.findall(r"(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)", s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4Pr6x/1)

**Details**:

- `(?<!\d)` -  no digit is allowed before the current location
- `\d{5}` - 5 digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed after the current location.

Answer (score 4):

Using [word boundary (`\b`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), which match at beginning / end of the word:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\b\d\d\d\d\d\b", "Helpdesk-Agenten (m/w) Kennziffer: 12966")
['12966']
```

`\d\d\d\d\d` can be replaced with `\d{5}`:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\b\d{5}\b", "Helpdesk-Agenten (m/w) Kennziffer: 12966")
['12966']
```

---

**UPDATE** If you need to get `12966` out of `12966abc`, see Wiktor Stribiżew's answer which use negative lookaround assertions.

or

```
>>> [match.group(2) for match in re.finditer(r'(\D|^)(\d{5})(\D|$)', '12345abc')]
['12345']
```

or combining simple regular expression with list comprehension:

```
>>> [match for match in re.findall(r'\d+', '12345abc') if len(match) == 5]
['12345']
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl, Thank you for pointing that. I will update the answer.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, Wiktor Stribiżew came up with the solution I would posted, so I updated with another solution.