# Regular expression to match a phone number in string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to match a phone number on a specific format like  `021-768-4444` to do that i wrote a program that recognizes a valid phone number when a string is passed to the regular expression, and successfully my program accomplish this task, but when i pass a phone number other than this format it also recognizes rather than show me `None`:

Here is the code:

```
import re
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')
mo = phoneNumRegex.search('My number is 415-555-42424854-201.')
if mo is not None:
    print('Phone number found: ' + mo.group())
else:
    print("Pattern is not matched")
```

Above code give me this output:

```
Phone number found: 415-555-4242
```

while i expecting it to be `None` because i know that the search() method will return None if the regex pattern is not found in the string.

But if i pass a correct phone number it works as expected:

```
mo = phoneNumRegex.search('My number is 415-555-4242.')
```

It's very strange behavior for me, can someone guide me where i am wrong?
Any help would be really appreciated.Thanks

Comment: The pattern *is* found in that string. You did not specify that the string shouldn’t be *longer*.

Comment: why donwvote? what's wrong in my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I suspect the phrasing of your question might have something to to with it. Your search didn't work the way you expected. The re was not behaving strangely. Your expectations were off. Debugging goes much quicker if you start from the assumption that the fault is with your code and not with the programing language.

Comment: **Dupe of [Regex matching 5-digit substrings not enclosed with digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807864/regex-matching-5-digit-substrings-not-enclosed-with-digits)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<!\d)\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}(?!\d)
```

https://regex101.com/r/VAaA7k/1

```
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}(?!\d)')
```

https://www.ideone.com/4Ajfqe

---

To prevent other unwanted matches, use a stronger regex pattern

```
(?:^|:|(?<=\s))(\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4})(?=[\s,;.]|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/VAaA7k/5

Comment: Thanks it helped me, very useful answer with better sources

Comment: much appreciated. I think this is very strong regular expression in my case

Answer (score -1):

`search` check if the regex matches part of the string. i.e search the regex in the string.
`match` check if the regex matches the entire string.

```
mo = phoneNumRegex.match('My number is 415-555-42424854-201.')
mo is None //True
```

Another option is to match the start and end of the string -

```
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'^\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d$')
mo = phoneNumRegex.search('My number is 415-555-42424854-201.')
mo is None //True
```

Answer (score -1):

As @deceze reply, as per your given regular expression, it's working as you never mentioned "it shouldn't be longer".

> Adding \b at end of regex will work for you

like below

`import re
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\b')
mo = phoneNumRegex.search('My number is 415-555-42424854-201.')
if mo is not None:
    print('Phone number found: ' + mo.group())
else:
    print("Pattern is not matched")`

Comment: This wouldn't work with for example `My number is 1234-567-8901.`, as it finds a match, although there is none - see https://www.ideone.com/RuILit