# Re-replacing in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a function that replaces the string with a

`~(number)~`.

Now let's say I have a string that says
`This is the replacement of ~26~ and ~524~. We still have 2 cadets left. Have2go for the next mission.2`

I want to replace all the 2 in a string with `~86~` but when I am doing so the 2 in `~26~` and `~524~` also getting replaced to `~~86~6~` and ```~5~86~4~.

```js
function replaceGameCoordinate() {
  var string = `This is the replacement of ~26~ and ~524~. We still have 2 cadets left. Have2go for the next mission.2`
  var replaceArr = ['2'];
  let patt = new RegExp(`${replaceArr[0]}`, 'gm')
  var newString = string.replace(patt, "~86~");
  console.log(newString);
}
replaceGameCoordinate();
```

The expected output should be :

```
This is the replacement of ~26~ and ~524~. We still have ~86~ cadets left. Have~86~go for the next mission.~86~
```

Comment: Your regex is working for all 2 but this is not replacing the 2 in have2go

Comment: `/(?<!\d)2(?!\d)/` is what you need. ``new RegExp(String.raw`(?<!\d)${replaceArr[0]}(?!\d)`, 'g')``

Comment: [Here  it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41807955/3832970). This is a very typical and common issue, no need for another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need a different regex rule. You don't want to replace `2`. You want to replace `2 when it's not next to another number or ~`.

In order to do this, you can use lookaheads and lookbehinds (although lookbehinds are not yet supported by regexes in JS, I believe, but at least with lookaheads) :

```js
const input = "This is the replacement of ~26~ and ~524~. We still have 2 cadets left. Have2go for the next mission.2";

const regex = /2(?![\d~])/gm // Means : "2 when it's not followed by a digit \d or a ~"

console.log( input.replace(regex, "~86~" ) )
```

Comment: It will stil match `12`

Comment: Indeed, but not `~12~` or `~123~`, so it fits the bill. Feel free to submit a better answer :)

Comment: ...and OP replied `Your regex is working for all 2 but this is not replacing the 2 in have2go`. So it looks like my proposition still works better :)

Comment: if I have something like 2~24~ then it is also not replacing that 2 . I also want to replace that

Comment: So, define a precise set of rules. My reply answered the original problem, but now the rules have changed.